# Split dataset into train and valid folder using python

Tags: python, function, validation, dataset, training-data

I want to write a python script to split the dataset into train and valid folders, keeping the train folder with (high in variance).

My dataset:

- Images ~3319
- Annotations ~3319

**Note : The images with same file-name should not be splitted,
for instance,

```
myimage.pdf-1.png 
myimage.pdf-2.png 
myimage.pdf-3.png
```

**

The above images should not be splitted as they belonged to the same pdf document.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection

Comment: Can you please ellaborate, since I am new to python. @user972851

Comment: Expanding more specifically on user972851, you may find the `train_test_split()`
 function from Sklearn useful. This can be used to split a dataset into testing and training subsets. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

Comment: Can you write a python code using train_test_split() fitting my above case ?

Comment: Please try to solve your problem yourself first! Share your approach incl. code. Then ask a specific question why and where you are stuck. Don't expect to get complete, copy&paste customized solutions provided.